# Swapping delimited strings in an excel column

Tags: excel

I have a column in a very large excel spreadsheet that is in some cases incorrectly formatted.  It should contain first a street address, then a name, separated by a hyphen, as shown:

123 Main St-Smith

However, some are formatted in reverse, such as:

Jones-231 High St

All the addresses start with a numeric and all the names start with an alpha.  I am looking for a macro or code that would swap only the name and address where it is incorrectly formatted.  I have tried turning it into a comma delimited to separate them out, but since they only occur intermittently I am still left with fixing them one by one manually.

Any suggestions?  I am by no means an Excel macro expert.  Thanks!

Comment: Are there any spaces in the last names?

Comment: As I said there can be, there can also be symbols such as the ampersand in the case of a partnership.  Such as 'Smith & Jones'.  By the way, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on the hyphen then look for spaces in the second element.

```
dim i as long, tmp as variant

with worksheets("sheet1")
    for i = 2 to .cells(.rows.count, "a").end(xlup).row
        tmp = split(.cells(i, "a").value2, "-")
        if cbool(instr(1, tmp(1), " ")) then _
            .cells(i, "a") = join(array(tmp(1), tmp(0)), "-")
    next i
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote

- Street name is any string that begins with a digit and ends with either a hyphen or the end of the string
- Name is any string that starts with a non-digit and ends with either a hyphen or the end of the string

---

This can be done using just native VBA, (although at first I was going to use Regular Expressions)

- split on the hyphen
- rearrange depending on if first starts with a number or not
- do some error checking in case no hyphen present or don't have the number and non-number start as specified.

---

```
Option Explicit
Function fmtAddressName2(S As String) As String
Dim sAddr As String, sName As String
Dim v As Variant

v = Split(S, "-")

On Error GoTo badFormat

If IsNumeric(Left(v(0), 1)) And Not IsNumeric(Left(v(1), 1)) Then
    sAddr = v(0)
    sName = v(1)
ElseIf Not IsNumeric(Left(v(0), 1)) And IsNumeric(Left(v(1), 1)) Then
    sAddr = v(1)
    sName = v(0)
Else
    GoTo badFormat
End If

fmtAddressName2 = sAddr & "-" & sName
Exit Function

badFormat:
    'return unchanged string
    fmtAddressName2 = S

    'or could return an error message

End Function
```